# How to use word break, asterisk, word break in Regex with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a complexe precompiled regular expression in Perl. For most cases the regex is fine and matches everything it should and nothing it shouldn't. Except one point.

Basically my regex looks like:

```
my $regexp = qr/\b(FOO|BAR|\*)\b/;
```

Unfortunately `m/\b\*\b/` won't match `example, *`. Only `m/\*/` will do which I can't use because of false positives. Is there any workaround?

*from the comments -* false positives are: `**`, `example*`, `exam*ple`

*what the regex is intended for? -* It should extract keywords (one is a single asterisk) coworkers have entered into product data. the goal is to move this information out of a freetext field into an atomic one.

Comment: What characters are allowed before and after `*`?

Comment: all word break characters like SOL (start of line), EOL, whitespace, non a-z 0-9. `\b` at it's finest

Comment: `\b` is the boundary between a word char and a non-word char. There're no word boudary between `*` and space.

Comment: What false positive do you encounter with `/\*/`?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=308744

Comment: false positives: `**`, `example*`, `exam*ple`

Comment: What exactly is the regexp supposed to match? It looks like you want to treat `*` as a regular word-character. But it's not, so `\b` will not work as you expect. Remember that `\b` doesn't match any character at all - it matches zero-width *boundaries* between different classes of characters (`\w` and non-`\w`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want to treat `*` as a word character.

```
\b
```

is equivalent to

```
(?x: (?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w) )
```

so you want

```
(?x: (?<![\w*])(?=[\w*]) | (?<=[\w*])(?![\w*]) )
```

Applied, you get the following:

```
qr/
    (?: (?<![\w*])(?=[\w*]) | (?<=[\w*])(?![\w*]) )
    (FOO|BAR|\*)
    (?: (?<![\w*])(?=[\w*]) | (?<=[\w*])(?![\w*]) )
/x
```

But given our knowledge of the middle expression, that can be simplified to the following:

```
qr/(?<![\w*])(FOO|BAR|\*)(?![\w*])/
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Perl does not consider `*` to be a "word character", and thus does not recognize a word boundary between a space and an asterisk (whereas it *does* recognize one between the `r` and the `*` in `foobar*`).

The solution is to first decide what you *do* want to consider "word" and "non-word" characters, and then check for that explicitly.  For example, if you want your words to consist *only* of letters 'A' to 'Z' (or their lowercase versions) and `*`, and for everything else to be treated as non-word characters, you can use:

```
/(?<![A-Za-z*])(FOO|BAR|\*)(?![A-Za-z*])/
```

This will match the strings `FOO`, `BAR` or `*`, provided that they're not preceded or followed by a character that matches `[A-Za-z*]`.

Similarly, if you, say, want to consider everything except whitespace as non-word characters, you could use:

```
/(?<!\S)(FOO|BAR|\*)(?!\S)/
```

which will match `FOO`, `BAR` or `*`, provided that they're not preceded or followed by a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Note that using `[A-Za-z*]` changes the result for `FOOÉ`. Note that using `\S`, that changes the result for `FOO.`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
my $regexp = qr/(?:\b(FOO|BAR)\b)|(?:^| )\*(?:$| )/;
```

In action:

```
my $re = qr~(?:\b(FOO|BAR)\b)|(?:^| )\*(?:$| )~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_");
}


__DATA__
FOO
BAR
*
exam*ple
example*
```

**Output:**

```
OK : FOO
OK : BAR
OK : *
KO : exam*ple
KO : example*
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also matches alle the false positives

Comment: looks like komodo has hung up, sorry